# angular ionic $http sends null data to rest API

Tags: angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am calling a rest API using 
method is "POST"
requestData is

```
{
    'username': user.userName,
    'password': user.password,
    'deviceID': deviceid,
    'latlng': null,
    'pincode': null
}

var req = {
    method: method,
    url: 'http://url/' + Api,
    headers: {
        'Token': 'Basic bUY5VkV0eHBOK3JUYUF1TGJjM1FHRGh4N1hYejhYSEw=',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: {
        'contentType': 'application/json',
        'content': requestData
    },
}
console.log(req);

$http(req).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

My rest APA is

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/authenticateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST, consumes = "application/json")
public AuthenticateUserBean authenticateUser(@RequestBody final AuthenticateUserBean authenticateUserBean) {
```

I am receiving null values for all the data such as username, password.
It is an ionic hybrid app with angular js.
I am calling it using chrome.
Cors is already disabled.

Comment: See my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42852534/3543808) and post the screenshot of request in developer tools network tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request format has few issues:

- No need of `contentType` in `data`
- You can directly send your `requestData` as `data`

Try with below code:

```
var req = {
    method: method,
    url: 'http://url/' + Api,
    dataType: 'json',
    headers: {
        'Token': 'Basic bUY5VkV0eHBOK3JUYUF1TGJjM1FHRGh4N1hYejhYSEw=',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    data: requestData,
}
console.log(req);

$http(req).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Comment: Thanks. That did it. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm glad it helped @RaviSolanki